# Style input file filename text

Tags: css

Is there a way I can style the ***file name text*** that is displayed next to the Browse `button` (shown in the image)? I want to move it via `position:absolute` and stuff. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not. Each browser's design of the control is different. You've just hit one of the many snags in web design. However, [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) site offers a cool JavaScript based solution that masks the native file input with a pseudo look-alike that can be styled to your liking.

Comment: you mean the filename of your browse form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this jquery plugin, use it if you think it could help you

this is my [a demo of the plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/5M4td/) in action

you could just use it like this

**javascript**

```
$('input').fileprettify();
```

**css**

```
.selected-file{
    color: green;
}
```

what this plugin does is replace the file input field with a button and a span containing the selected file, and you can then style the button and the selected file text using css, the good thing about this is that you will use the same style for all browser.